# how to make a VPI in verilog?

Tags: verilog

When I run across on web,  I found this question [how to use verilog PLI communicate with c by ncverilog compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044001/how-to-use-verilog-pli-communicate-with-c-by-ncverilog-compiler)

And I followed the last answer but It does not work.
One of the error is hello_vpi.c :  "vpi_user.h No such file or directory"
hello_vpi.c 12  : error 's_vpi_systf_data'undeclared(first use in this function)
....

What should I for solving?

## update

@Greg ::  My simulator is Incisive15.10.002 and Linux6.0.

I have got a problems which is when I ran like this `gcc hello_vpi.c -fPIC -shared -o hello_vpi.so -I  /cadence/Incisive/Incisive15.10.002/tools.lnx86/include` then I have got some message as following.

> hello_vpi.c : Infunction 'register_hello' :
> hello_vpi.c :16: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type.

And I have got some error messages as following when I run this command
`ncverilog test.v +access+r -v hello_vpi.so`

> ...
> *W.LIBNOU : Library "hello_vpi.so given but not used.
> ...
> $hello;
> unrecognized system task or function
> ...
> libvpi.so cannot open shaed object file:  No such file directory or file is not valid ELFCLASS64 library
> ...
> *E, MSSYSTF  : user defined system task or function( $hello) registered during elaboration and used with in the simulation has not been registered during simulation.

I have no idea  what am I suppose to do?

Comment: Is the simulator part of you PATH variable? If not, you may want to add the `-I` (capital 'i') with a path to your simulator. Some simulators have the file in a lib or bin director.

Comment: Also, some simulators come with there own gcc in the installation director, usually in the bin directory. If you compile with this gcc, it should have the path to `vpi_user.h` already included. If you need more help, you will need to update your question and tell use what simulator and OS you are using and if you are using an IDE.

Comment: @Greg  : I have updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the spaces after `-I`

```
gcc hello_vpi.c -fPIC -shared -o hello_vpi.so -I/cadence/Incisive/Incisive15.10.002/tools.lnx86/include
```

You can also try: (note: I'm guessing the path the the gcc that comes with Incisive)

```
/cadence/Incisive/Incisive15.10.002/tools.lnx86/bin/gcc hello_vpi.c -fPIC -shared -o hello_vpi.so
```

If `ncverilog test.v +access+r -v hello_vpi.so` doesn't work, try:

```
ncverilog test.v +access+r -loadvpi ./hello_vpi.so:register_hello
```

Comment: All of it not works except for last one. " ncverilog test.v +access+r -loadvpi ./hello_vpi.so:register_hello " is works. Thanks but I don't know why are those command not work? Should I have to use like the last commads per every time?

Comment: Create another void function (say *register_all*), and have this function call all the other functions you want register. Then use *register_all* instead of *register_hello* when running ncverilog.

Comment: This is off the topic question, I am not sure what should I have to learn between DPI vs VPI?  I am newbie and want to start something interface language. The VPI is really dead( according to surthelland)?

Comment: If you read Sutherland paper [The Verilog PLI is Dead (maybe) -- Long Live the the SystemVerilog DPI!](http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2004-SNUG-paper_Verilog_PLI_versus_SystemVerilog_DPI.pdf) carefully, you'll see in sections 7 and 8 that DPI cannot fully replace VPI. VPI (sometimes referred to as PLI 2.0) did replace PLI (aka PLI 1.0) as the old TF and ACC files were deprecated in 2005. VPI is not going away any time soon unless DPI or a future interface language can do the all the same functionality as VPI.

Comment: My general rule of thumb when I need something done in C/C++ with Verilog/SystemVerilog: if it can use DPI, then use DPI, else if it cannot be done in DPI, then use VPI. You should learn both if you can, but I would be higher emphasis on DPI as you will likely be using it more often.